# ActiveAdmin uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am getting the following error after deploying my application to my VPS. ActiveAdmin works fine on my local development environment, but once I deploy using capistrano, it looks like the gem is not being installed?

```
E, [2013-03-14T01:27:04.901577 #24972] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin (NameError)
/home/deployer/apps/papaya/releases/20130314052558/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

My gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'
# gem 'acts_as_tree', :git => 'git://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree.git'
gem 'closure_tree'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'slim'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'stamp'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.3.1'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'select2-rails'
# gem 'roo'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'
end
```

I am able to run the console without a problem and require `activeadmin`

```
deployer@pareto:~/apps/papaya/current$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'activeadmin'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: Can you verify that you and your VPS have the same version of Ruby?

Comment: Yeap, both running `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added a `require 'activeadmin'` to my active_admin.rb initializer and it works!

Answer (score 12):

#### What's Happening?

When requiring gems that define constants, like `ActiveAdmin` or `ActiveAdmin::Comment`, if for some reason during definition of that constant something goes wrong Bundler leaves that constant undefined and won't reraise the exception.

#### Possible Causes

`ActiveAdmin` depends on `ExecJS` and `ExecJS` needs a working JavaScript runtime. `ExecJS` will throw an error like this during definition of `ActiveAdmin` constant.

```
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
```

In this case, just install Node.js. `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

### How to Debug Problems Like This

1. Try to run Rails console. `bundle exec rails console`
2. If that fails, try to manually require problematic gem inside `irb` and work through its dependencies.
3. Require the gem or part if it that should be defined but isn't. When requiring manually Rubygems throw an exception describing the problem.
4. Work through exceptions and fix them until the problem is resolved.

Comment: I faced it too, so check your JS runtime.

Comment: @AlexTonkonozhenko This is about how to debug rather than check your js runtime. These kind of errors happen too often, consider understanding the approach.

Comment: I know, but I was surprised that ActiveAdmin depends on JS

Answer (score 10):

Try restarting rails server. Had similar problems which cleared up after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you might not have run bundle install in your production env.

try running `bundle install` in production env

Comment: Capistrano runs it when deploying

Comment: use 'bundler show activeadmi'n to see it really installed in prod

Answer (score 0):

@alexBrand's solution didn't work for me.

Instead, adding `require 'activeadmin/cancan_adapter'` inside the configuration block worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

uncomment the (gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby) gem from gem-file then bundle..it works

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to your `routes` and remove the `active_admin routes` and also run `rails destroy active_admin:install`