# Playing Hide and Seek with Constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm upping a Rails app from 6.0 to 6.1 and bumped into a really funky oops on the way. The app uses the latest ActiveAdmin. Works fine on Rails 6.0, however, on 6.1 halfway through the boot of the app (using the classic autoloader), the following is raised:

> /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.7.5/gems/activeadmin-2.9.0/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/action_builder.rb:3:in `module:ActiveAdmin': uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin::BaseController (NameError)

Adding a breakpoint one line before this error happens, I try the following:

```rb
[1] pry(ActiveAdmin)> ActiveAdmin.constants.grep :BaseController
=> [:BaseController]
[2] pry(ActiveAdmin)> ActiveAdmin::BaseController
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin::BaseController
from /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.7.5/gems/activeadmin-2.9.0/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/action_builder.rb:3:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
```

I'm baffled, how is this even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ActiveAdmin uninitialized constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401998/activeadmin-uninitialized-constant)

Comment: Nah, not related at all.